# What's a good hash to use between PHP and Python?

Tags: php, python

I have the luxury of starting from scratch, so I'm wondering what would be a good hash to use between PHP and Python.

I just need to be able to generate the same hash from the same text in each language.

From what I read, PHP's md5() isn't going to work nicely.

Comment: "isn't going to work nicely" ... in what aspect? in general: both languages have code for almost all available hash algorithms. which one to pick is up to your needs. what are your needs?

Comment: Just saying "I want to use a hash" doesn't make much sense.  Different hashes are good for different purposes.  For example, not all hash functions are [Cryptographic Hash Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function).  You should evaluate them for intended use (security criteria), performance, and ease of use (display/storage) rather than for which langauges support them.  Also, why won't MD5 work nicely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`md5()` always plays nicely - it always does the same thing because it is a standard hashing format.

The only tripping hazard is that some languages default return format for an MD5 hash is a 32 byte ascii string containing hexadecimal characters, and some use a 16 byte string containing a literal binary representation of the hash.

PHP's [`md5()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) by default returns a 32-byte string, but if you pass `true` to the second argument, it will return the 16 byte form instead. So as long as you know which version your other language uses (in you case Python), you just need to make sure that you get the correct format from PHP.

You may be better using the 32-byte form anyway, depending on how your applications communicate. If you use a communication protocol based on plain-text (such as HTTP) it is usually safer to use plain-text versions of anything - binary, in this case, is smaller, but liable to get corrupted in transmission by badly written servers/clients.

The binary vs. ascii problem applys to just about any hashing algorithm you can think of.

Answer (score 4):

What is it you want from the hash? (portability, security, performance....)

> From what I read, PHP's md5() isn't going to work nicely.

What did you read? Why won't it work?

> I just need to be able to generate the same hash from the same text in each language

Since PHP only provides crc32 (very insecure), md5 and sha1 out of the box, it's not exactly a huge amount of testing you need to do. Of course if portability is not an issue then there's the mcrypt and openssl apis available. And more recently the [hash PECL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php) gives you a huge choice.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use sha1 as it is implemented out of the box in both but has no collision valnurabilities like md5. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Collision_vulnerabilities